# DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM") allways gives 20:06

Tags: c#, datetime

In c# i'm trying to get the time with the following code:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM");
```

I fill this value into a ListView. Somehow it allways gives 20:06 but if I add a breakpoint before this point in my code and walk through it step by step it show me a different time while it is still adding 20:06.

Here's how i'm adding it:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(mItem.Naam);
item.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:MM"));
item.SubItems.Add(tafelnummer.ToString());

lstBarOverzicht.Items.Add(item);
```

When i'm going throug the code step by step and hold the mouse on "Now" then I see DateTime.Now {9-6-2015 21:02:15} but when I check the subitems of item then I see the resultview then I see subitems [1] {20:06}

Comment: Well for starters "MM" is for month, not minutes.  Use lower case m's for minutes

Comment: That's why. It's month 06. I've been looking for the answer for about 30 minutes now and really couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @juharr, why couldn't we just let him believe that he discovered how to pause the flow of time?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram hahaha. Wow that would have been something

Comment: google works wonders and could have saved you a lot of wasted time and or downvotes in my opinion..

Comment: @user3398922 The only valid reason for down votes is the "this question doesn't show any research effort".  As in you could lookup the [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and figured this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"))` instead of `"HH:MM"` `"MM"` is for format as month, `"mm"` is for minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking to show HOUR:MONTH.

You need:

```
item.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
```